# How to add SVG/text over a CSS Polygon in Angular

Tags: css, polygon

I want to make something like the one below.[Figma that I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwD9O.png)

I have my HTML like the one below.

```
<div class="quad"></div>
```

where my class quad is defined in CSS like the one below.

```
.quad {
  border-bottom: 100vh solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 20vw solid transparent;
  width: 60vw;
}
```

If I add SVG and the text something like below,

```
<div class="quad">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
           <img src="SVG" alt="Logo" width="200" height="80">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
           Beetle
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The result of the above change is:- [After adding SVG/text in quad div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmhFO.png)

**how should I add the beetle SVG and the text onto the CSS polygon correctly , just like the Figma?**

Comment: @RobertLongson The SVG and the text sit on the top of the polygon.
So basically SVG and text come in one row and then the whole Polygon.

Comment: Made the changes in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `position:absolute` to your `row` class:

```
.row{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  
}
```

I also suggest you look into css property `transform: skewY()` to draw that triangle on the left hand of your design. That way you can leave the rest of your container plain white and achieve the design you want. Here is a [website](https://wweb.dev/resources/css-separator-generator/) that lets you try `skewY()` with different angles.

[skewY() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skewY)